# How to create two custom cell in one table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `tableview` on that I want to create two custom cells. I have created two custom classes for `UITableViewcell`. If I am creating one class cell at a time. Then it is working right. But if I am creating both at same time. It is showing exceptions.

**Code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    check=@"a";


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    tb=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    tb.delegate=self;
    tb.dataSource=self;
    [self.view addSubview:tb];

    [tb registerClass:[imgTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CI];

    [tb registerClass:[_TableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CII];  // I think, problem is here.


}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 6;
}
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    if([check isEqualToString:@"a"])
    {

    IMGCELL=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CI];

    if(!IMGCELL)
    {

    IMGCELL=[[imgTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CI];
    }
    IMGCELL.feeds.text=@"HEHEHE";

    return IMGCELL;

    }

    else
    if([check isEqualToString:@"b"])
    {

    CELL=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CII];

    if(!CELL)
    {

    CELL=[[_TableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CII];
    }
    CELL.IMGV.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"band"];

    return CELL;
    }
    return nil;

}
```

**Exceptions:**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_TableViewCell feeds]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d5c660'
```

**Problem:Problem is, I am registering two classes to table view. Is there any method to `unregister` the class.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this is](https://www.dropbox.com/s/chnrc5uhqzr81cf/CustomTableView.zip?dl=1) the bast way to create custom cells to tableView, my example include delegate for button action inside a cell, try to use it, and i hope you resolve your problem, and this realization is useful to you in future projects.
For example your table view delegate method should look like here>

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     if (indexPath.row == 0)
     {
         CustomTableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomTableViewCell"];
         if(!cell){
             cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[CustomTableViewCell cell];
         }
         cell.tapDelegate = self;
         [cell fillCellWith:indexPath andSomeThingElse:@"test"];

         return cell;

     }
     else
     {
         CistomTableViewCell2 * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CistomTableViewCell2"];
         if(!cell){
         cell = (CistomTableViewCell2 *)[CistomTableViewCell2 cell];
     }

         return cell;

}
```

If you have a questions, about customizing this realization, i can help you...

Answer (score 0):

As usual, Define the following datasource methods of the tableview for loading the tableview with some data.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

## in cellForRowAtIndexPath Method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                              reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        containerObject = [objectCollection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell textLabel] setText:containerObject.store];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return cell;
    } else {
        static NSString* cellIdentifier1 = @"FeatureCell";

        FeatureCell *cell1 = (FeatureCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];
        if (cell1 == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier1 owner:nil options:nil];
            cell1 = (FeatureCell*)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        cell1.img1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shower.png"];
        cell1.img2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"parking.png"];

        return cell1;
    }
}
```

## OR Another SOlution

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    //We are doing some rough calculation for loading different xibs or different rows 
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        BlogpostCell *cell = (BlogpostCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BlogpostCell" owner:self options:nil];
//Assign the instance of the tableview cell that we have created in the custom cell
            cell = blogPostCell;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
        cell.postType.text = @"Cook said Apple has acquired 23 companies in the last 16 months and remained on the lookout for interesting technology and companies.Apple is not in a race to acquire the most companies or to spend the most money, but that doesn't mean we won't buy a huge company tomorrow afternoon, he said.And he warned shareholders not to focus too narrowly on short-term gains.If you're in Apple for only a week ... or two months, I would encourage you not to invest in Apple,he said.We are here for the long term";

        return cell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.row % 3 == 0) {
        MicroblogCell *cell = (MicroblogCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MicroblogCell" owner:self options:nil];

            cell = microBlogCell;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
        cell.postContent.text = @"After trying to penetrate the mid-range mobile segment with the outdated iPhone 4, Apple India has decided to offer buyback discounts on the MacBook if you are returning your old Apple laptop";

        return cell;
    }
    else {
        ShareCell *cell = (ShareCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ShareCell" owner:self options:nil];

            cell = shareCell;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
        cell.postContent.text = @"After smartphones, now almost every tech company is jumping onto smart wearable devices, many of them focusing on health, nutrition and fitness.";
        return cell;
    }
}
```

In the above code , where we are looking for a specific row index for loading the corresponding cell and returning the same.
We can also further customise the cell by calculating the dynamic height for different contents and showing the same

Comment: Thank you, but here condition is different. Say, application have two buttons. Clicking on first it should show table according to it. and for 2nd button, it should show according to it.@mehul